# Firestore pagination based on pageNumber and PageIndex

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I was looking at the Firestore document for pagination. It seems it is based on the last snapshot if you need the next document as per the below article :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

But I my end I am getting only `indexNumber` (pageNumber) and `pageSize`, like indexNumber (pageNumber) is 2 and page size is 4 . How can I achieve the pagination here with the index and `pageSize`? I can put `pageSize` in limit(4), but how can I get the subset of the documents starting from the index which is 2, or page number 2 . Below is the code written in the document.

```js
import { collection, query, orderBy, startAfter, limit, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";  

// Query the first page of docs
const first = query(collection(db, "cities"), orderBy("population"), limit(25));
const documentSnapshots = await getDocs(first);

// Get the last visible document
const lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
console.log("last", lastVisible);

// Construct a new query starting at this document,
// get the next 25 cities.
const next = query(collection(db, "cities"),
orderBy("population"),
startAfter(lastVisible),
limit(25));
```

Comment: What do you mean by index 2?

Comment: its the page number

Comment: So you want to create SQL-like pagination? So you need to know the total number of pages in advance?

Comment: yes , i have the count of the total number of pages and items also . What would it be for page 2 . Is it like hitting the await getDocs(first) to get all documents .

Comment: So you basically want to click and 4, and jump to the fourth page, right?

Comment: If the page Number is 1 , it should give 1-4 content , if page number if 2 , it should give 5-8 .. and so on .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252980/discussion-between-mohit-h-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: I will write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why would you implement such a pagination, since nowadays we are using that so-called infinite scroll. It's true that you can [count()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#use_the_count_aggregation) the number of documents in the collection and divide it by the number of documents per page, so you can get the number of pages, but does it worth it?

Most likely it doesn't since it will require you to read all the documents beforehand, and this sounds a little costly. Firestore does **not** support index or offset-based pagination. As the [official documents state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors), pagination requires that you provide a DocumentReference that represents the starting point for the next query. This basically means that your pagination will start at the beginning of the query, and then you can load other results using the last document you see on the page (screen).

The solution above can be implemented very easily and it costs far less compared to the traditional method, as you'll always load the data progressively in smaller chunks.